This puzzle is delicious
This is part 5, see for part 4: Help. It's not compiling!

This puzzle is delicious :)



?
?
?
?
?
?
?
?
















The images are in order:

APPLE pie, ICE CREAM cake, BLUEBERRY cake, PECAN pie, PISTACHIO pie, BLACKBERRY pie, STRAWBERRY pie, CHERRY pie

Notice that

Most of the these are types of pies...

So

If we take the first 8 digits of 'pi' - 3.1415926 - and match them to the words:

We get

3 - ap[P]le
1 - [I]ce cream
4 - blu[E]berry
1 - [P]ecan
5 - pist[A]chio
9 - blackber[R]y
2 - s[T]rawberry
6 - cherr[Y]

Meaning this is:

a PIE PARTY!!

Delicious indeed!


Correct of course! Could you show the digits of each image instead of the 'etc'? Makes it a bit more clear I think

@Lezzup done! I solved before I went to bed last night so was being lazy :P

Rot13(Guvf zhfg or n phygheny guvat, orpnhfr 2 bs gubfr ner qrsvavgryl Pnxr sbe zr)

I would accept this but not all images are of pie. Image 2 and 3 are cakes. But aside from that the rest of it does give the answer

@ForwardEd yeah I originally had them as cakes and changed to pies for aesthetics, but it’s probably more accurate to have them as cakes so I’ll rollback
